# How to pick available device on the run from perfecto

Tags: selenium, mobile, automated-tests, qaf, perfecto

During execution I want to get the list of available devices from perfecto cloud and execute my test cases on any available devices from the pool. How can I achieve this with QAF - Perfecto framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic device selection, **don't** use `deviceName` capability, instead use [capabilities that allow you to specify the device characteristics](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Using+capabilities+to+select+device) to select device. In order to set capabilities refer [setting driver capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html)

Comment: Is there a way to execute my cucumber scenario in all available scenario ? Please help ?

Comment: will you please provide more details what you mean by **cucumber scenario in all available scenario**?

Comment: Sorry for the typo - its cucumber scenario in all available devices.